# Disable and Hide WP-JSON

Tags: redirect, rest-api, json

Without the use of plugin how is possible to deactivate wp-json and redirect the URL to a 404 page. Whenever someone calls `example.com/wp-json` it redirects it to 404 page instead of loading?

I tried to do it via htaccess but it's not working any possible solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Does adding this to functions.php work ?

```
add_filter('json_enabled', '__return_false');
add_filter('json_jsonp_enabled', '__return_false');
```

Comment: I don't see either of those in the latest 6.4 code. There is a [rest_jsonp_enabled](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_jsonp_enabled/) but it wouldn't turn on the REST API on its own, and [rest_enabled](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_enabled/) has been deprecated in favour of using rest_authentication_errors (yuck)

Answer (score 0):

Add the this snippet to your `wp-includes/functions.php` file

```
 add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', 'wp_snippet_disable_rest_api' );
   function wp_snippet_disable_rest_api( $access ) {
      return new WP_Error( 'rest_disabled', __('The WordPress REST API has been disabled.'), array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code()));
   }
```

from [wpdynamic.com](https://wpdynamic.com/wordpress-developer/wordpress-code-snippets/how-to-disable-the-wordpress-json-rest-api-without-plugin/)